# What is the problem with this question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, specific-question

[What is the meaning of mail in CCPA?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/57902/where-to-file-the-mail-request) What is the problem with this question? Every thing is clear.I am asking that does mail in CCPA refer to physical mail and if yes why dont websites provide such an option?

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to speculate about why anonymous voters disliked your post. Perhaps it's because, despite 10 versions, the post still doesn't answer questions like those posed in the comments (*e.g.* "I have no idea what 'small g frm' or 'non-compliant mr' mean.").

People on Law.SE tend to be generalists, so it helps to explain any technical terms that you can't avoid using.